# Exception Thrown at Deployment

Tags: asp.net, iis

The following exception is being thrown at deployment. I'm running my application on IIS 7. I've tried cycling the App Pools and restarting the application with no success. Any ideas for troubleshooting would be greatly appreciated. I'm suspicious it might have something to do with  .NET versioning, but that's mere speculation. Thanks in advance!

FullException="   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessException(Exception ex) |    at         System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseStringInternal(String text, Encoding fileEncoding) |    at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseString(String text, VirtualPath virtualPath, Encoding fileEncoding) |    at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseFile(String physicalPath, VirtualPath virtualPath) |    at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.Parse() |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen this error happen when the `Inherits` page directive is one value in development, but is different when deployed.

Verify the source of your page (`PageName.aspx` to see if the `Inherits` name matches the class name in your other environments).